# A problem in downloading NetBeans 8.2 IDE

Tags: netbeans-8

I can't download netbeans 8.2 it shows me this error:
`Cannot load native library which is strictly necessary to work correctly Exception: org.netbeans.installer.utils.exceptions.NativeException: Cannot load native library from path: native/jnilib/windows/windows-x86.dll`.
Please help me

Comment: When you say `download`, do you mean run?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `JAVA_HOME` and write the command `echo %JAVA_HOME%` to make sure the problem is solved